# Django QuerySet for ManytoMany relation using Bridging Table

Tags: django, orm

I am new to Django and was looking for an efficient way to retrieve and post to a ManytoMany relation using an intemrediary table.

models:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Actor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, primary_key = True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class NormActors(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    actor = models.ForeignKey(Actor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have checked the documentation and it got confusing, so any reference would be helpful as well. If on request, I want to send -

1. for /movies: get list of all movies + details with the actor names in the respective movies
2. for /actors: get list of all actors + details with the movies they have been in

Should the ORM query look something like this?

```
actor = Actor.objects.get(name="XYZ")
movies = actor.movie_set.all()
```

How should I go about fr the first one?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should explicitly declare the m2m and identify the through table as such:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    ...
    actors = models.ManyToManyField('Actor', through='NormActor')
```

Now for any movie you can do `movie.actors.all()`, and for any actor you can do `actor.movie_set.all()`.

Note, if you only have those two fields on NormActor, you don't actually need to declare it explicitly; you can remove that model and the `through` attribute and Django will manage it for you, with the added bonus that in the admin interface you can now edit actors inline with movies.

Answer (score 1):

To help me avoid confusion, I always call a "`through`" table by the name of 2 other tables. Thus, in your case, I would have done:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, primary_key = True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    movies = models.ManyToMany('Movie', through='ActorMovie',
                               related_name='actors')

class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ActorMovie(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    actor = models.ForeignKey(Actor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Notes:

- the use of `related_name` is important and imagine it's the *reverse* direction: you declared the ManyToMany in `Actor` so reverse is `Movie -> Actor`
- `'Movie'` in quote because it's declared *after* this declaration. You can remove quotes but then declare `Movie` class first.
- same for `ActorMovie`
- with a `ManyToMany` declared this way you can access in both directions (= from `Actor` but also from `Movie`) in a very clear way, for example two working and very clean queries.

Examples:

```
# get all film with Harrison Ford:
for movie in Actor.objects.filter(name="Harrison Ford").movies.all():
    pass  # do whatever with movie

# get all actors from Die Hard movie:
for actor in Movie.objects.filter(name__istartswith="Die Hard").actors.all():
    pass  # do whatever with actor
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the movies related to an actor, you need to have ManyToMany relationship with Movie model with respect to Actor model.

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Actor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, primary_key = True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    movies = models.ManyToManyField(Actor)
```

Remember, you need to define Movie model before you creating a manytomany relationship with the Actor model.

```
actor = Actor.objects.get(name="XYZ")
movies = actor.movies.all()
```